# How to Solve DLL error in access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

I am developing an Excel project in Access using VBA. My project is working in Access 2007, but it does not work in Access 2003. If I try to run the file, it shows the DLL error. Anyone know how to debug this error?

Comment: Can you show exact error message? And why do you consider that ms access 2007 version will work on 2003?

Comment: It seems that you create a new account every time you ask a question. I can see 7 Raams here with very low rep.

Comment: @hgulyan I think if you look up John you will find the same thing.

Comment: How in the world can anyone answer this question if you don't even bother to specify the actual error? It could be any of thousands of DLLs causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty difficult to know what's causing your problem without knowing what error message you are getting and where it's occurring.

My best guess says that you are have a problem with a reference. Usually the best way to fix this is to change your code to use late binding if the version of Excel will not always be the same on every machine.

Consider the following 3 examples:

```
'This is early binding.
Dim oXLS As Excel.Application 
Set oXLS = New Excel.Application

'Create a new instance of an Excel Object using late binding
Dim oXLS As Object 
Set oXLS = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Set your object to an instance of Excel that is already open using late binding
Dim oXLS As Object 
Set oXLS = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
```

It's easier to program using early binding because you can use intellisense. However, if your target machines might have differing versions of Excel you should consider using late binding in your production/deployment version for better compatibility.